# Python -- How is my list out of range?

Tags: python, list, arraylist, range, outofrangeexception

The assignment was to let the user choose to either read the data file or to write to the data file.  I figured out how to write to it but I cannot understand my current error: that my list is out of range.

Can someone tell me how my list is out of range?

I've done everything right, I believe, but I'm honestly not sure how my list is out of range.  Please help me guys.  Thanks!

```
#Run again

useAgain=bool(True)

while useAgain:

#Display Options
    print("\nYou may either read or write to the file:\n"\
          "\n'1' - To read and display records in the data file."\
          "\n'2' - To order.\n")

    choice=str(input("Please enter your choice here: "))


    def func_read():
        cs7Assn7=open("cs7Assn7.txt",'r')
        line=cs7Assn7.readline()
        places=line.split('+')
        userID=places[0]
        widgetsNum=places[1]
        gidgetsNum=places[2]
        doodadsNum=places[3]
        print("Customer ID: ",userID,"\nNumber of Widgets: ",widgetsNum,\
              "\nNumber of Gidgets: ",gidgetsNum,"\nNumber of Doodads: ",\
              doodadsNum,"\n")

    def func_order():
        userID=str(input("Please enter your user ID(2 letters"\
                         " followed by 3 numbers: "))
        widgetsNum=abs(int(input("Number of Widgets you would"\
                                   " like to order: ")))
        gidgetsNum=abs(int(input("Number of Gidgets you would"\
                                   " like to order: ")))
        doodadsNum=abs(int(input("Number of Doodads you would"\
                                   " like to order: ")))

        items=open("cs7Assn7.txt",'a')
        items.write(str(userID) + str(abs(widgetsNum)) + str(abs(gidgetsNum))\
                    + str(abs(doodadsNum)) + '\n')
        items.close()

    if choice=="1":
        func_read()
    elif choice=="2":
        func_order()
    useAgain=str(input("\nWould you like to run this code again? Type 'Y' to"\
                       " run or 'N' to stop: "))
    useAgain=useAgain.lower()
    if useAgain !="y":
        useAgain=bool(False)
```

Comment: At which line is the error?

Comment: We need more details than this. What line? What have you tried? What are some examples?

Comment: can you paste the traceback of the error?

Comment: I assume you are getting the error while reading the file.
Could you provide the line/row in the file `cs7Assn7.txt` for which you are getting the error?

Comment: i assume the list that is the problem is `places`? We need to see the file it is being created from.

Comment: In `func_read` you assume that your 4 fields are seperated by `+` but in `func_order` you are not writing the `+` between the fields. The 4 fields are not seperated at all by any character. A `+` between two strings just concatenates them and does **not** add a `+` character between the strings

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are getting the error on either of these lines:

```
widgetsNum=places[1]
gidgetsNum=places[2]
doodadsNum=places[3]
```

The reason is some of the lines in your text file is not having three '+' symbols.
Hence, on splitting, you are not having a list of 4 items. And hence, the error.